# Allow user to choose download path : MVC 5 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There might be possibility of duplication...but I didn't get any answer

How can I allow user to select downloadpath while clicking Download button?

I need to use that folder path only in my web application.

Any solution will be appreciated.

I am using jquery as well to have download path.

Answer (score 0):

Create your HTML form:

```
<form id="downloadForm">
    <label for="downloadPath">Select Download Folder:</label>
    <input type="file" id="downloadPath" webkitdirectory directory multiple style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" id="downloadButton">Download</button>
</form>
```

Add jQuery to handle user interaction:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // When the "Download" button is clicked, trigger the file input click event
        $("#downloadButton").click(function () {
            $("#downloadPath").click();
        });

        // When the user selects a directory, store the path in a variable
        $("#downloadPath").change(function () {
            var selectedPath = $(this).val();
            // You can now use 'selectedPath' in your web application as needed
            console.log("Selected path: " + selectedPath);
        });
    });
</script>
```